# Adding math symbols in a string

Tags: objective-c, addition, symbols

How could I add `a` and `b` without using the `+` symbol, because I am assigning the `+` symbol in the `c` variable?

I know how to form an expression using the above data as shown in the code below, but I don't know how to get the output of that expression using NSExpression.

This is my code:

```
int a=10;
int b=20;
NSString *c=@"+";

NSString *d=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%@%d",a,c,b];

nslog(@"d=%@",d);//d=10+20
```

After this, how do I get the answer 30?

Comment: In `[Java]` or `[Objective-C]`?

Comment: Looking at his code I'd say Objective-C.

Comment: what kind of workplace you have?

Comment: Objective-C to print the result

Comment: @sayalSnaking: Why did you change the contents of this question to something completely different?? Nobody will understand the answers if  he cannot read the original question! You should post a new question instead.

Comment: but what can i do . i can't delete this question

Comment: You cannot delete questions that got multiple answers. Why do you want to delete it? You got an answer that helped! - I have done a "rollback" to your original question.

Comment: You did it again! Why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;
NSString *c = @"+";

NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@ %d", a, c, b];
NSExpression *e = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:s];
int result = [[e expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil] intValue];

NSLog(@"%d", result);
```

Comment: thanks martin am got the result.

Comment: :NSArray *quantityPrice = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",nil];                         NSExpression *e= [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"add:to:" arguments:quantityPrice];                                            
   int result = [[e expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil] intValue]; I am getting error use this code.

Comment: @SnakingPrabhu: There is a simpler solution: `NSArray *quantityPrice = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",nil]; int result = [[quantityPrice valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"] intValue];`

Comment: thanks martin am got the output...Insteadof sum functions  other functions are avg,mul,div,sub etc working r not

Answer (score 4):

If you want to find the sum of a and b, you can:

```
-(-a-b)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using math you can add two numbers without using addition like this

```
b*=-1
int result = a-b;
```

Comment: Though I found the question a bit odd, this is the smartest tackle on it!

Answer (score 3):

Use following code to add two number without '+' sign.

```
int add(int x, int y) {
    int carry = 0;
    int result = 0;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
        int a = (x >> i) & 1;
        int b = (y >> i) & 1;
        result |= ((a ^ b) ^ carry) << i;
        carry = (a & b) | (b & carry) | (carry & a);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: There's even two `+` signs in the `for` loop :).

Comment: @Yogendra Joshi you can still avoid + sign in your loop ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function that extracts the operator (in this case the +) from the string and calculates based on that. I urge you to view at least the first couple of episodes from the [programming course by Paul Hegarty](http://itunes.apple.com/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255?mt=10) of Stanford University. You will build a calculator that does stuff you want to know to solve your problem.